# Why does this return a reference to the global window object, even though 'this' is within another function

Tags: javascript

```
if (typeof obj == 'undefined') {
  obj = {};
}

obj.thing = new function () {
  if (typeof this.global == 'undefined') {
    this.global = (function () {return this;})();
  }
}
```

this.global is assigned to this inside of a function. So, why does this return a reference to the window object?

```
console.log(this) > DOMWindow
console.log(obj.thing.global) > DOMWindow
console.log(window) > DOMWindow
```

I would love to understand this better.

Comment: `new function () {}` (invoking an anonymous function expression as a constructor)? Well, that's certainly something that I haven't seen before...

Comment: Switch to strict mode. It will make more sense then (`this` will be `undefined`).

Comment: My question was more about why this happens. Not that I don't want it, or do want it. This code functions correctly but I would like to understand what is happening more completely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ES 3 and ES 5 there is a *this* keyword associated with every execution context (ES 3) or Lexical Environment (ES 5). The value is set according to the rules for entering global or function code as described in ECMA-262 [§10.4](http://es5.github.com/#x10.4).

In your code you have:

```
  this.global = (function () {return this;})();
```

Where the result of calling an anonymous function is assigned to *this.global*. Within that anonymous function, the value of *this* is set according to the algorithm in [§10.4.3](http://es5.github.com/#x10.4.3).

Since the function is called without setting the value of *this*, and the code is not in strict mode, the value of *this* is set to the global object (which, in a browser, is generally the window object) per step 2 of the algorithm.

If the code was in strict mode, then the value of *this* within the anonymous function would be *undefined*, which is the value that would be assigned to *this.global*.

Comment: the reference for `this` within an EC has nothing to do with whether or not the called function is anonymous or not.

Comment: I don't think anyone here said that it did. It has been said many times that it is related to how the function is called (except for ES5 *bind*).

Answer (score 0):

`this` is a keyword which always returns the current context. Try this:

```
if (typeof obj == 'undefined') {
  obj = {};
}

obj.thing = new function () {
  if (typeof this.global == 'undefined') {
    var self = this;
    this.global = (function () {return self;})();
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes always. It is always the current context. You can change the current context by calling a member function or by using `apply`.

Comment: @DarkFalcon—the *this* keyword **is not** "context". In EMCA-262 ed 3, a function's this keyword was one parameter of its *execution context*, along with the activation object, variable object, scope chain, and so on. The value of *this* is set by the call, and can be any object, even null, and may a different object for each call of a function.

Comment: @DarkFalcon—should also add that in ES5, *exection context* has been replaced by *Lexical Environment*, and *variable object* by *environment record* (more or less). And *this* can be *undefined* in strict mode.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that within your self-invoking anonymous function, the context is the *global object* aka `window` there. So it returns the `window` reference. Even if the `new` keyword creates a new object as context for your outer function. That outer context does not matter for the invocation of your self-invoking function.

To avoid that, you can modify the code slightly into:

```
obj.thing = new function () {
  if (typeof this.global == 'undefined') {
    this.global = (function (that) {return that;})(this);
  }
}
```

Comment: The value of a function's *this* keyword has nothing to do with context (or scope or whatever), it is **entirely** to do with how the function was called (except for ES5 bind, which is relevant here).

Comment: @RobG: `this` is all about context. That is why it is called the `this context variable`. Whatever object it references depends on many factors, one of those is invocation. However, `.call` and `.apply` also do modify this reference which has nothing to do with es5.

Comment: Anyone who calls *this* the "context variable" doesn't understand the meaning of "context" (or *this*) in javascript.

Comment: In ECMAScript, "context" is used in the term "execution context", which is defined in ESMA-262 §10. In ES 3, the execution context includes the variable object (§10.1.3), scope chain (§10.1.4), activation object (§10.1.6), this value (§10.10.7) and arguments object §10.1.8). In ES 5 the variable object becoms a variable environment with an environment record binding the variables. So the *execution context* provides a lot more information than the *this* keyword and *this* provides only a small component of the execution context.

Comment: @RobG: are you serious? You just copy&pasted the spec and still say that its not about context? Listen and repeat: EC = scope chain, AO/VO and **this value**. So `this` is part of the execution **context**.

Comment: Serious? Yes. *this* is one (often little used) component of an execution context. It's like saying the scope chain is the context, or arguments object is the context. They are all part of the same execution context.

Comment: Serious about what? Its a common mistake for people to think that the `this value` is part of the AO. Since it indeed is part of the `execution context` its called `this context variable`. Now come again and explain why "anyone who calls it like that does not understand the meaning of context", please.

Comment: Your initial statement that "the context is the global object" is misleading, the relevant "context" was function code (i.e. inside the anonymous function used to assign the value). To say "So [this] returns the window reference" is not a logical conclusion, because the value of *this* in a function is set according to how the function is called (except for ES5 bind), its value is not dependent on a function's execution context (even though it is part of it).

Answer (score 0):

`this` in javascript is really tricky. It does not mean what you think it means and can indeed have its value substituted [in lots of little ways](http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/08/30/understanding-javascripts-this/) depending on how the function is invoked. Although it can help with optimization and gives you a certain degree of power and javascript-knowledge-points, you might want to avoid using it until you are comfortable with the idea.

It is better to think of 'this' as a special variable that contains extra information the invoker of the function passed in.  If you want to lock down the value you can do it with the call/apply methods on functions or the browser Function.bind or _.bind in libraries like underscore.js.

```
var x = {
  name: "George",
  hiThere: function() { return "hi "+(this.name || "no value") ; }
}

x.hiThere(); // hi George

var thisWillBeGlobal = hiThere;
thisWillBeGlobal() // hi no value

var manuallyBoundToGeorge = function() {
  return x.hiThere();
}    
manuallyBoundToGeorge(); //hi George (always)
manuallyBoundToFred = function() {
  return x.hiThere.call({name: 'Fred'});
}
manuallyBoundToFred(); //hi Fred (always)

var hiGeorge = Function.bind(x.hiThere, x);
hiGeorge(); //hi George (always) - same as manual bind above
```

notice that Function.bind is not avilable in older browsers and it is generally preferred to use something like underscroe's _.bind

- You would of course still use `this` when working with libraries like jquery that pass information through it.